# google people api search by phonenumbers

Tags: google-people-api

I'm trying to use "searchContacts" method of the Google People Apis to search contacts by phone number but the result is always empty.

If I set the name of one of my contacts in query paramters, It works fine.
If I set the phone number in the query parameter, no result is returned to me.

I also trying to use "The test panel" in the Google documentation page (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts) but I have the same end.

Is this possibile?
If yes, How should I set the query parameter?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the canonicalForm of the phoneNumber without the `+` sign.

**Example:**

[image]

**Request parameter:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: no working at all

Comment: What is the "names" of the contact? Maybe it is the phone number of your contact

Comment: For some reason, when I search in the test API page it works, when doing the same vía googleapis PHP only searching by name is working for me. I'm sure is not the readMask.

Comment: @Tushar same here still not workin