# searchContacts with phone number query is broken

Tags: google-people-api

Using the [searchContacts API method] (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts) used to support searching by telephone number - indeed this is called out in the documentation:

> The query matches on a contact's names, nickNames, emailAddresses, phoneNumbers, and organizations fields that are from the CONTACT source.

It no longer returns results when using a phone number as the query. Is this deliberate, or a bug?

As per [google people api search by phonenumbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052056/google-people-api-search-by-phonenumbers) I have tried a query of "canonical format without plus". I have also tried "canonical format with plus" and "exact number as stored".

#### Name query still works

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchContacts?readMask=names%2cphoneNumbers&query=Go Ogle&pageSize=30
```

returns

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "person": {
                "resourceName": "people/c832768086350305259",
                "etag": "%EgcBAgsuNz0/GgECIgwxZGVYd20reHpEUT0=",
                "names": [
                    {
                        "metadata": {
                            "primary": true,
                            "source": {
                                "type": "CONTACT",
                                "id": "b8e96298f3117eb"
                            }
                        },
                        "displayName": "Go Ogle",
                        "familyName": "Ogle",
                        "givenName": "Go",
                        "displayNameLastFirst": "Ogle, Go",
                        "unstructuredName": "Go Ogle"
                    }
                ],
                "phoneNumbers": [
                    {
                        "metadata": {
                            "primary": true,
                            "source": {
                                "type": "CONTACT",
                                "id": "b8e96298f3117eb"
                            }
                        },
                        "value": "020 7031 3000",
                        "canonicalForm": "+442070313000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Search by name works]

### Phone number query fails

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchContacts?readMask=names%2cphoneNumbers&query=442070313000&pageSize=30
```

returns

```
{}
```

[image: Search by number fails]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query function does indeed seem to be broken at the moment. My tests gave the same results and the question you linked shows that it clearly worked in the past.

I found a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221756860) on Google's issue tracker. A Googler already replied to it saying that they were able to reproduce it and filed an internal report. It's a matter of time until they fix it so you may want to keep track of that thread or post on it yourself to apply some pressure.

Comment: I didn't realize they had a bug tracker so thankyou for the useful info!

Answer (score 0):

The bug didn't went away although they say it was closed and verified
In order to get the same functionality I had to be creative, the documentation says:

> The query matches on a contact's names, nickNames, emailAddresses,
> phoneNumbers, and organizations fields that are from the CONTACT
> source.

The names, emailAddresses, phoneNumbers and organizations are important fields where you don't want to have garbage, but on my case at least the nickNames had no usage, so I simply add the phone number as nick name and the search works like charm.

Keep in mind that if you have many previous contacts you will have to write a script that will copy their phone number to the one of the nicknames fields.

Enjoy :)